# running a stored proc from a select statement with or without loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table filled with profile IDs in a sql server database:

```
select WhateverID from Whatevers
```

With each ID return from this query, I need to run a series of 5 stored procs in order against it, like so:

```
EXEC MyStoredProc WhateverID, 'Value 1'
EXEC MyStoredProc WhateverID, 'Value 2'
EXEC MyStoredProc WhateverID, 'Value 3'
EXEC MyStoredProc WhateverID, 'Value 4'
EXEC MyStoredProc WhateverID, 'Value 5'
```

What is the best way to combine these two structures so that it runs until all IDs are covered from the initial query?

Comment: You could use a cursor

Comment: This is a common situation that many people face. The question and answers will hopefully prove helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql here quite effectively by building your dynamic string and then executing the whole thing in one step. Here is a simple example of how you could do this. The exec statement is commented out but you should get the idea.

```
create table #Something
(
    WhateverID int
)

insert #Something (WhateverID) Values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'EXEC MyStoredProc ' + CAST(WhateverID as varchar(4)) + ', Value 1;'
            + 'EXEC MyStoredProc ' + CAST(WhateverID as varchar(4)) + ', Value 2;'
            + 'EXEC MyStoredProc ' + CAST(WhateverID as varchar(4)) + ', Value 3;'
            + 'EXEC MyStoredProc ' + CAST(WhateverID as varchar(4)) + ', Value 4;'
            + 'EXEC MyStoredProc ' + CAST(WhateverID as varchar(4)) + ', Value 5;'
from #Something

select @SQL
--exec @SQL

drop table #Something
```

Comment: I used this solution because it worked and I saw ways of altering it that could be used to solve some other issues I was having. That being said, I think the cursor would have worked as well, I just like this way better.

Comment: Glad this works for you. A cursor would also work here but it will be slower, noticeably on a larger dataset.

Comment: @optionsix : yes, a CURSOR _would_ have worked, it just isn't necessary for a simple operation like this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a cursor, a simple, narrow (Ids only) table-valued in-memory variable will suffice.

```
declare @Ids table (id integer primary key not null)
Insert @ids(id) Select whateverId from whatevers
Declare @id integer
While exists(Select * from @ids) Begin
   Select @id = Min(id) From @ids
   EXEC MyStoredProc @id, 'Value 1'
   EXEC MyStoredProc @id, 'Value 2'
   EXEC MyStoredProc @id, 'Value 3'
   EXEC MyStoredProc @id, 'Value 4'
   EXEC MyStoredProc @id, 'Value 5'
   Delete @Ids where id = @id
End
```

or

```
declare @Ids table (id integer primary key not null)
Insert @ids(id) Select whateverId from whatevers
Declare @id integer
Declare @param varchar(20)
Declare @i tinyInt = 0
While exists(Select * from @ids) Begin
   Select @id = Min(id) From @ids
   while @i <= 5 Begin
      Set @i += 1
      Set @param = 'Value ' + str(@i, 1,0)
      Exec MyStoredProc @id, @param
   End
   Set @i = 0
   Delete @Ids where id = @id
End
```

Comment: You say don't use a cursor but instead use nested while loops??? A well defined cursor will almost always outperform a while loop.

Comment: -1 this is unnecessarily complicated and inefficient: 1) you say to not use cursors but give 2 cursor-based examples. Neither is using a T-SQL `CURSOR`, but operationally they are the exact same row-by-row approach. And they are less efficient than a true `CURSOR` due to needing the `Delete` and 2 `SELECT`s per each row, which gets expensive as the number of rows to process increases. It is a myth that `WHILE` loops are faster than `CURSOR`s. 2) The second example is slower as it has a while loop per each row. 3) These examples are more code and hence more error-prone than a true `CURSOR`.

Comment: Can't disagree more, unless you use a fast-forward, [read only]cursor, (which is under the surface little different from using t-sql on an in-memory table variable) any other cursor will be much slower, as it requires server side tracking and management of cursor position, status, update capability, etc. Also, as to error-prone-ness, cursor options and syntax are much more extensive and complex, contributing to greater opportunities for error.

Comment: @CharlesBretana: studies have been done showing that T-SQL CURSORs are indeed faster, but yes, that likely requires either `FAST_FORWARD` or `FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY`. The only downside to a real CURSOR is table locking when hitting real tables, which can be avoided by using `STATIC` which copies the result set to a temp table first, and hence not locking the base tables.

Comment: We are tempting the SO gods to kick us over to the blog section, but yes, you are correct, and since (as you note), that approach creates a temp table, but still requires careful understanding of the many pitfalls associated with using cursors inappropriately, I prefer to just use the temp table variable directly, where syntax is (to me) simpler, and cannot create all (any?) of the performance issues that improper use of a cursor can cause.

Comment: And I have seen those studies, but none of them use a temp table variable with only one 4-byte column with a clustered primary key index. Run the same tests using that structure and the results might surprise you.

Comment: @CharlesBretana : Ok. So to be fair, I will try to run some tests tomorrow. If I find that you are correct about the performance then I will remove the -1 (and will just respectfully disagree about which method is more/less complex ;-).

Comment: @CharlesBretana : I tested your first example, a `STATIC` cursor, and a `FAST_FORWARD` cursor (both `READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY`). Both cursors were _much_ better Logical Reads and Elapsed Time, and better (enough) on CPU time. I improved your WHILE loop by: add `SET @id=NULL` after the `DELETE`, move `SELECT MIN(id)` to after the new `SET @id`, copy `SELECT MIN(id)` to just before the `WHILE`, and change the `WHILE` test to be `@id IS NOT NULL`. Logical Reads improved 20% and Elapsed Time 86%! But still doesn't beat the slower of the 2 cursors. We can go to chat, but not until mid-late next week.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the use of cursors. Though they can be annoying, they're good for stuff like this

```
DECLARE @WhateverID int
DECLARE WhateverCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT WhateverID FROM Whatevers
OPEN WhateverCursor

FETCH NEXT from WhateverCursor into @WhateverID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC MyStoredProc @WhateverID, 'Value 1'
    EXEC MyStoredProc @WhateverID, 'Value 2'
    EXEC MyStoredProc @WhateverID, 'Value 3'
    EXEC MyStoredProc @WhateverID, 'Value 4'
    EXEC MyStoredProc @WhateverID, 'Value 5'

    FETCH NEXT from WhateverCursor into @WhateverID
END

CLOSE WhateverCursor
DEALLOCATE WhateverCursor
```

Edit: Typos Also didn't see similar answer was posted already

Comment: The other answer, by mohan111, is similar, but yours is syntactically correct :).

Comment: Yeah after editing it like 8 times :p I should stay of SO while waiting for the coffee to kick in.

Comment: Nothing wrong with going back to edit. I see it as a positive that you checked your work and fixed it :).